# Kendo Grid Inline Editing shows password text instead of plain text

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I am currently have challenge with entering plain text in Kendo Grid inline editing mode instead of password mode it shows by default. My other pages are pretty fine. This issue is peculiar to the page in the screenshot. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The data annotation on the property is [DataType(DataType.Password)]. commenting it out made it work. It's an inherited code though.